# Filling null values based on the proportion of the categories in that column

Tags: python, pandas, fillna, proportions

I have the following data

```
col=['black','black','black','grey','white','grey','grey','nan','grey','black','black','red','nan','nan','nan','nan','black','black','white']
dd=pd.DataFrame({'color':col})
dd.replace('nan',np.NaN,inplace=True)
dd.sample(5)
Out[1]: 
    color
8    grey
14    NaN
7     NaN
2   black
9   black
```

The following is the proportion of each color in the column

```
dd.color.value_counts(normalize=True)
Out[2]: 
black    0.500000
grey     0.285714
white    0.142857
red      0.071429
```

Now I want to fill the null values based on these proportions above.
So 50% of null values will become black, 28% grey,14% white and 7.1% red

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can randomly assign the value based on the probability using `numpy.random.choice` (https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.choice.html)

STEP #1. Calculate the probabilities for each values.

STEP #2. Assign the values to `NaN` based on the probability so that the values are assigned as the original distribution.

This way will work regardless of the number of values.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

col = ['black','black','black','grey','white','grey','grey','nan','grey','black','black','red','nan','nan','nan','nan','black','black','white']
dd = pd.DataFrame({'color': col})
dd.replace('nan', np.NaN, inplace=True)
print(dd.color.value_counts(normalize=True))
"""
black    0.500000
grey     0.285714
white    0.142857
red      0.071429
Name: color, dtype: float64
"""

probability = list(dd.color.value_counts(normalize=True).values)
dd['color'] = dd['color'].apply(lambda x: np.random.choice(['black', 'grey', 'white', 'red'], 1, replace=False, p=probability)[0] if pd.isna(x) else x)

print(dd.color.value_counts(normalize=True))
"""
black    0.526316
grey     0.315789
white    0.105263
red      0.052632
Name: color, dtype: float64
"""
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you for putting me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

```
cond1 = dd['color'].isnull()
dd.loc[cond1, 'color'] = dd[~cond1].sample(cond1.sum())['color'].values
```

as data size increases, probability converges. run following code for checking result

```
import numpy as np
col=['black','black','black','grey','white','grey','grey','grey','black','black','red',np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,'black','black','white']
dd=pd.DataFrame(col * 10000, columns=['color']) # *10000 for large data
cond1 = dd['color'].isnull()
dd.loc[cond1, 'color'] = dd[~cond1].sample(cond1.sum())['color'].values
dd.value_counts(normalize=True)
```

result:

```
color
black    0.500444
grey     0.284111
white    0.143944
red      0.071500
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. What if the size of the data set remains the same? In that case, how would we fill the null values based on the proportions of categories within that column.

Comment: The size is small, but is it possible randomly filling it in proportion? explain with your example. Your example has 5 nans, what is the meaning of filling them proportionally?

Comment: So i am working on a data frame with 401525 rows. This data frame contains a column "standard_color". In this column, there are 5341 Null values which should be filled. Also in this data frame, approximately 22% of the color are black, 17% are white, 15% grey etc. So i want to fill the null value with the same proportion, so 22% of 5341 null values should become black, 17% white and so on and so forth. I hope you get my point now.

Comment: then why not try running solution code?

Comment: It is a mysterious example of filling 5 nans in proportion, so I just increased size of example. I think you're asking unnecessary questions without even running. Just run the solution code.